# Displaying titles and buttons inside of ion-header-bar

Tags: ionic-framework

Not sure if it's ionic thats buggy or something else ..

I am creating a simple header (and nothing else)

```
  <ion-header-bar class="bar-positive">
    <h1 class="title">Title!</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <button class="button">Right Button</button>
    </div>
  </ion-header-bar>
```

I expect to see a "Title" and a button on the header bar. But that doesn't happen.

```
http://plnkr.co/edit/vPkirnzlFX1I9B7W9H8N?p=preview
```

Answer (score 0):

problem was with the ionic bundle:

using the below solved the issue:

```
<script src="//code.ionicframework.com/nightly/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
```